# How would I best go about populating this array with original objects?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I have an array:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList();
```

And I want to add people to the array, but I don't think it will work because all the objects will have the same name.

```
Person person = new Person();
person.firstName = firstNameTextField.getText();
person.lastName = lastNameTextField.getText();
//Etc
people.add(person);
```

My question is, can I populate array with objects of the same variable name? If not, how can I still use `People` objects?

Comment: An object is unrelated to a variable that refers to it.

Comment: Try it out first and ask a question if you actually have a problem. If you loop it, you'll assign a new `Person` object to `person` but this won't mean the previous one is gone: you just don't reference it from `person` anymore.

Comment: So I will be able to reference the object using the array's index?

Comment: @Mattbettinson yes, you will be able to.

Comment: Implement `Person.clone()` and use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you won't have any issue with what you're describing.

You'll end up with something like this:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.firstName = firstNameTextField.getText();
person.lastName = lastNameTextField.getText();
people.add(person);

person = new Person(); // <-- reinitializing person.
person.firstName = firstNameTextField.getText();
person.lastName = lastNameTextField.getText();
people.add(person);
```

At this point List contains two unique Person objects.  Iterating over them might look something like this:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList();
// add a bunch of Person objects like we did above

for(int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Found person: " + people.get(i).firstName);
}
```

The fact that you continue to make the people.add(person) call, doesn't necessarily you're repeatedly adding the same person to your list over and over again.  In the case shown above, unique Person objects are being added and can be accessed independently as shown in the for loop.

Comment: `people[i].firstName` should be `people.get(i).firstName`

Answer (score 0):

Objects are unrelated to their variable names! Yes, ofcourse it will work!

Answer (score 0):

If you are Lazy you can also use a Constructor in People.

```
class Person {
 public Person(String firstname, String lastname) { 
 this.firstname=firstname;      
 this.lastname=lastname; 
}
}
```

and then ...

```
people.add(new People("tom", "lastnameoftom"));
people.add(new People("Susi", "SusisLastname"));
```

and so on..

But to answer your Question.. Everytime you use a new on a var, it will be reinitialized. the Compiler will translate this:

```
People people = new People();
people.setSetter(data);

people = new People();
people.setSetter(otherdata);
```

to (example)

```
People a = new People();
a.setSetter(data);

People b = new People();
b.setSetter(otherdata);
```